# can I show a specific part of a page using document.getElementById(href)?

Tags: javascript, iframe, document, href, getelementbyid

if I have a page called "content page":

```
<body > 

<p id="part1">Tread ... inch. </p>

<p id="part2">Tread ... inch. </p>

<p id="part3">Tread ... inch.</p>

</body>
```

and another page with this java script(code in [close icon doesn't appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210633/close-icon-doesnt-appear/6210683#6210683) ).

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popupBox.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

show content of part one : <a href="TreadDepth.html" onClick="return show_hide_box(this,400,400,'2px solid')">Click Here</a>.
show content of part two : <a href="TreadDepth.html" onClick="return show_hide_box(this,400,400,'2px solid')">Click Here</a>.
show content of part three : <a href="TreadDepth.html" onClick="return show_hide_box(this,400,400,'2px solid')">Click Here</a>.

</body>
```

if I want to retrive a specific part of a content page to be shown in the popup box, is that possible?

I mean in this part at popup.js:

```
var boxdiv = document.getElementById(href);
```

can I specify an ID of a tag in the href of the page to retrive it? like :

```
var href = an.href; 
var boxdiv = document.getElementById(href).getElementById("Show The content of this ID tag!");
```

any idea?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want. IDs have to be unique throughout the page and `"Show This Part!" is not really a valid ID.

Comment: I've edited my question, hope it is clear now :$

Comment: It's no clearer than before. [Sample code](http://sscce.org/) should be complete, concise and correct. Yours is short, but that's about all. One thing that would be helpful is sample HTML.

Comment: I've edited it again, and this is the folder of my question code: http://www.2shared.com/file/f6MKO61P/popupBox.html
thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for reminds me of how [WML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Markup_Language) works, with multiple cards on a single page, only one of which is shown at once. It's possible to load the content of one page in another, but not the way you envision.

As you might guess from the name, `getElementById` gets an element based on the ID attribute, nothing else. Instead, you have to load the content of the other page, at which point you can show parts of it on demand.

In popupBox.js:

```
var show_hide_box;
# it may not be best to set width, height and border this early,
# but it simplifies the code below
(function(width, height, border) {
    var pages = {};

    function show_hide_box(link) {
        var path = (/^[^#]*/.exec(link.href))[0];
        if (pages[path]) {
            show_content(pages[path], link);
        } else {
            fetch_content(link, path);
        }
        return false;
    }

    function show_content(path, link) {
        var id = (/#(.*)/.exec(link.href))[1];
        if (content[id]) {
            # Show content[id], which is a DOM node
            ...
        } else {
            # the page exists, but not the fragment. Could search 
            # content.elements for the 
            ...
        }
    }

    function fetch_content(link, path) {
        $.ajax({
            url: link.href,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
              pages[path] = {elements: $(data).filter('p')};
              pages[path].elements.each(function (idx, elt){
                  # TODO: handle elements w/ no id
                  pages[path][elt.id] = elt;
              });
              show_hide_box(link);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                # Can't load the content, so just load the page.
                window.location.href = link.href;
            }
        );
    }

    window.show_hide_box = show_hide_box;
})(400,400,'2px solid');

$(function() {
    $('.external_content').click(function(evt) {
        show_hide_box(this);
        evt.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

In the other page:

```
<body>
  show content of <a href="TreadDepth.html#part1" class="external_content">part one</a>.
  show content of <a href="TreadDepth.html#part2" class="external_content">part two</a>.
  show content of <a href="TreadDepth.html#part3" class="external_content">part three</a>.
</body>
```

It's generally considered better form to subscribe event listeners in a script, rather than [inline](http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/) in HTML. Also, don't use "[click here](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere)" for link text.

Comment: this is exactly wt I'm looking for! thnx outis ^_^ 
since I'm not that professional, I was trying to complete the code and of course, understand it..
this is wt I came up with:http://www.2shared.com/document/h3ilUFF7/popupBox.html
I feel like I'm missing something, like loading the whole page then choose the part ID, right? :$

Comment: @Evanescence: instead of a file sharing site such as 2shared (which requires others to download, then open files), try a site such as pastebin.com or one of the many other sites that let you quickly [post code](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/top-5-places-to-share-code-quickly/) which let others view the code in browser or download at their discretion, as well as tons of other features. In any case, make sure you're posting sample code rather than your full production code, which will have too much extraneous material to wade through.

Comment: ... I'm not sure what you're asking about when you mention "loading the whole page then choose the part ID". `fetch_content` above shows a way of loading page content, and `show_content` choses a particular element based on ID. All that's not shown is how to display the element (since you didn't appear to have a problem with that part, and in any case it would be the topic of another question).

Answer (score 0):

What you basically want, as I understood it, is to show content of a given URL in a box/container/view on your site.

There are some ways to achive this. Here are two of them:

- The most recommanded is to load the
  content via [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/). (The link goes
  to the jQuery Ajax Documentation -
  jQuery will make your live easier ;-)
  )
- An other way could be to use [iFrames](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEEQFjAD&url=http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_iframe.asp&ei=Wm7nTfzOJ9DqOcbjjc8J&usg=AFQjCNH8HkmfnfDZFmQMNGRePoZoFhBKwg&sig2=QT-Hwj0zO7BO_8xejBq5ZA).

Comment: in the code I use they use the second way, could u give me an example\demo\Sample code that use the first way? I'm still learning  jQuery and AJAX so I still need more examples to understand it well :$
thank u very much!

Answer (score 0):

No man. Its not possible.

I have checked your code and found the original site where it was posted.
The URL: http://example.nemikor.com/creating-dialogs-on-demand/

If you check on the three links on that site, you can see that each three of those links reference three different uris.